# bash: recursively move all matched files in sub directory of parent to new sub directory

Tags: linux, bash

I've been attempting to recursively move all matched files in sub directory of parent to new sub directory.  The current structure is as follows (there are files other than wave files, they would need to be excluded):

```
.
├── a
│   ├── a.wav
│   └── media.dir
├── b
│   ├── b.wav
│   └── media.dir
├── c
│   ├── c.wav
│   └── media.dir
└── d
    ├── d.wav
    └── media.dir
```

And I'd like to move the wave file in each directory, to its corresponding media.dir.  I have this so far, which is working for the match, but not the file move (when I echo instead of mv, I can confirm the file):

```
for dir in */
do
    find . -iname '*.wav' -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} mv '{}' "$dir/media.dir"
done
```

Comment: Clarify - you want the equivalent of `mv a/a.wav a/media.dir/; mv b/b.wav b/media.dir/; ...`?

Comment: That is correct, however it looks like the changes below are what I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `find "$dir"` rather than `find .` in your code:

```
for dir in */
do
    find "$dir" -iname '*.wav' -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t "$dir/media.dir"
done
```